# Relationships doesn't exists when I convert Physical Data Model to Access Database using Power Designer

Tags: powerdesigner

When I convert Physical Data Model to Access Database using Power Designer I don't see the relationships in the access database, only the tables, why?

Comment: I don't know, it works for me. In a direct `Generate Database` from the physical model, I have statements like `alter table ENTITY_1 add constraint FK_ENTITY_1_RELATIONS_ENTITY_2 foreign key (ATTRIBUTE_4) references ENTITY_2 (ATTRIBUTE_4)` in the script, and I can see the joins when I open the `Relationships Tool` in Access...

Comment: How do generate the Access database? Via script, or ODBC? Do you have such foreign key definitions in your script? Do you have references in the physical model?